# how can i know which version my working folder is based on?

Tags: svn

I am using Tortoise SVN,  how to know the working copy's version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click in Windows Explorer and get Properties.  (The Windows properties, not the Properties on the TortoiseSVN submenu.)

TortoiseSVN adds a new tab to this window called Subversion.  The current revision number is one of the attributes listed, among others.

Answer (score 2):

You can right-click the folder, select Properties, and then click on the Subversion tab to see this info.

Note that different folders or even files can be at different revision numbers in your working copy, depending upon how you updated.